# Magento timestamp timezone problems

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have a client who recently implemented SAP using the "Insync" module. The Magento app is showing the timezone correctly but the db is showing the timestamps in UTC. The folks at Insync say we need to correct the issue. Is there a way to change how timestamps are created?

Comment: FYI: I have talked to the client and told them to communicate to Insync that they should be adjusting their app to accommodate the time difference.

Comment: Magento shows the time in local time per the time zone set up in configuration and stores the records with UTC time stamps. That pretty much is how most databases work these days so there is interoperability (think multi-national/multi-timezone). Insync just needs to know the time-zone and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I told them but they seem to think we need to change our DB server

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, please share your solution and mark it as accepted so that we can learn from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the connector to read the Magento application for the time instead of the db server.

This solved the problem. (Which really was never a problem)